# How can I get 2checkout sandbox for laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, 2checkout

I'm looking for 2checkout's sandbox. But, I can't find it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

2Checkout supported the `demo` parameter for sandbox/test checkout.

You can use 2Checkout sandbox just adding this element `'demo' => 'Y'` or `'demo' => true`

Read more: [Transition Guide for 2CO Sandbox](https://knowledgecenter.2checkout.com/API-Integration/Transition_guides/Transition_Guide_for_2CO_Sandbox)